# ¿Cómo deshabilitar el ploteo de información al compilar latex desde python?

Tags: python, latex

Estoy compilando documentos de latex desde python en Ubuntu 16.04. pero quiero deshabilitar los mensajes de información que aparecen en el shell cuando lo hago (los mismos mensajes que aparecen, por ejemplo, en TexWorks cuando compilas).

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
def compila_latex(nombre):

    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Hay un error con la compilación del documento.')

    cmd  = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
    proc.communicate()

    retcode = proc.returncode
    if not retcode == 0:
        os.unlink(nombre + '.pdf')
        raise ValueError('Error')

    list_files     = os.listdir(os.curdir)
    list_aux_files = [fil[len(nombre):] for fil in list_files if fil[:len(nombre)] == nombre]

    for end in list_aux_files:

        if end != '.tex' and end != '.pdf':
            os.unlink(nombre + end)
```

Supongo que algo tendré que hacer con la línea de la variable cmd, pero no se muy bien el qué.

Nota: compilo dos veces para que aparezcan índices y demás.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más sencilla en Python 2.x podría ser algo así:

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['pdflatex','-interaction','nonstopmode', nombre + '.tex']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

out, err = proc.communicate()
```

Al configurar `stdout` y `stdin` como `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` abrimos una tubería dónde se redirigirán estas salida, luego en `out` tendras la salida estándar y en `err` la salida de error, mientras no las imprimas, no veras estas salidas en la consola.

Comment: Perfecto, es justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias!!